# Implement short urls (tinyurls) for twitter in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, short-url

how do you convert full(long) urls into short urls(like tinyurls) in C# for twitter? I imagine this is probably very simple with the right api. Does anyone know of a good api for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using tinyurl.com in a .Net application ... possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366115/using-tinyurl-com-in-a-net-application-possible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using tinyurl.com in a .Net application ... possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366115/using-tinyurl-com-in-a-net-application-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just published [an article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/services/programmatically-creating-a-tiny-url-from-bit-ly) about doing this from bit.ly in a C# application.

Note that bit.ly requires a free login key that you will need in order for the code to work.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to make a request to `http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url={url}` substituting the `{url}` with the url you want and read the content of the page.

Here's an example:

```
public string ShortUrl(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url={0}", url));
        Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but a proper API is required for my project. This is almost like a work around. I would rather first use, if possible an api built for this, then resort to other methods if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a nice example on http://psc.fyi

You can find an explanation on http://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/Creating-a-URL-shortener-using-ASPNET-WepAPI-and-MVC

Comment: Try to explain it rather than posting external links.