# How to consume Tiny-URL API for mvc4 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, tinyurl

I want to use Tiny-URL API in MVC4, any ideas how can I consume that API in my solution?

I refereed its documentation but it was in PHP document [link](http://www.tiny-url.info/open_api.html)

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/366149/1726419

Comment: I want using http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create/ api ...This is documentation http://tiny-url.info/open_api.html and when i am using it gives me an error of invalid url. please help.

Comment: I'd highly recommend having a look at http://restsharp.org/. I've used it in several projects and handles converting XML/JSON encoded responses to objects :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [use same code as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366115/using-tinyurl-com-in-a-net-application-possible/366149#366149), but with different uri.

First of all, you need to request API key and set `apikey` variable accordingly. Then select provider string which you will use [from API docs](http://www.tiny-url.info/open_api.html#provider_list) (I use `0_mk` for `0.mk` provider in example below).

Then you can compose url and make request like this:

```
string yourUrl = "http://your-site.com/your-url-for-minification";
string apikey = "YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE";
string provider = "0_mk"; // see provider strings list in API docs
string uriString = string.Format(
    "http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create?url={0}&apikey={1}&provider={2}&format=text",
    yourUrl, apikey, provider);

System.Uri address = new System.Uri(uriString);
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
try
{
    string tinyUrl = client.DownloadString(address);
    Console.WriteLine(tinyUrl);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("network error occurred: {0}", ex);
}
```

According to the docs, the default format is `format=text`, so you don't need to specify it. You can also use `format=xml` or `format=json` if you want, but you'll need to parse output then (and you'll have `state` field in response and may process errors).

**UPDATE:** With .NET 4.5 to asynchronously get tiny url **await** keyword may be used with `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync()` function  (you should do this in function, marked with **async** keyword):

```
...
string tinyUrl = await client.DownloadStringAsync(uriString);
...
```